# Windows Forms very slow under Windows7?

Tags: .net, winforms

Today a colleague of mine said that GDI+ and Windows Forms are very slow under windows 7. He also mentioned that GDI+ is not longer accelerated by hardware. Unfortunatly I do not have a Win7 machine here and the results I got from google are not very clear. So my question is: Is GDI+ slow under Windows 7?

Thank you for Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GDI+ has never been hardware accelerated.  No significant complaints after Win7 was introduced, this is likely to be fud.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he meant GDI acceleration.  Here is a discussion about it: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/136811-windows-7-and-gdi-hardware-acceleration/

And on Stack Overflow: [GDI has been accelerated. Does anyone know when this happened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141758/gdi-has-been-accelerated-does-anyone-know-when-this-happened)