# MVVM View representation when using a list and multiple view model properties

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

In reference to [a previous question with an MVVM answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270351/assistance-required-with-delegates-example/16270867?noredirect=1#comment23358668_16270867)

I'm trying to build on this, instead of simply using text in the listbox, I want to be able to insert a UserControl that displays 3 different properties of the Model (or do i need another ViewModel?).

I could easily add the UserControl directly into the ListBox, but I'm pretty sure this wouldn't be congruent with the MVVM pattern.

Just wondering if someone could help.

**The UserControl Code**

```
public partial class ActionModule : UserControl
{
    public ActionsViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public ActionModule()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

**The UserControl UI**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DelegateAction.ActionModule"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<DockPanel>
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
        </Style>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinWidth="150" Text="Title"/>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Action" MinWidth="150" />
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="75" Text="Owner"/>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" MinWidth="75" Text="Score" />
</DockPanel>
```

**The Model for the UserControl**

```
public class ActionItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public short Score { get; set; }
    public Action Action { get; set; }
}
```

In the ViewModel from the last example, we had these collections, do they stay as a collection of ActionItem's or does it need to be of ActionModule's?

```
public class ActionsViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ActionItem> AvailableActions { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ActionItem> SelectedActions { get; set; }

    public ActionItem FocusedAction1 { get; set; }
    public ActionItem FocusedAction2 { get; set; }
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Are you using Caliburn.Micro? I would hazard this guess based on `PropertyChangedBase`, but maybe it's your own base class, so I'd like to be sure...

Comment: the collection of ActionItems is fine as the properties of the actionitem will be bound to your data template. But where is the listbox and where is the code which contains databinding? I am guessing there is no need for even user control, you can use datatemplate right away in your listbox

Comment: Refer to this msdn article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

Comment: Thanks I'm currently working through this to confirm it matches my needs but it's looking promising so far :)