# How to dynamically add controls to a WrapPanel in another class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm migrating from VB to C# and decided that WPF would be the best option for me as the programs I've been developing are highly GUI dependant based applications. However, C# is causing me a lot of headaches, confusion, and frustration when trying to get what are simple tasks in VB to work in C# code. In VB, I can get this working VERY easily. But in C#, after spending countless hours (now days) searching and playing with code, I'm still non the wiser how to get this working.

My scenario:

- I have 2 xaml pages.
- The first xaml page has a wrappanel.
- The second xaml page has a button that will create a new button and add it to the wrappanel in xaml page 1.

I can easily add a new button to the wrappanel when using the code below in page1.xaml.cs:

```
Button New_Button = new Button();
My_WrapPanel.Children.Add(New_Button);
```

I've also tried calling a method located in page1 from page2 to create the button but the new button does not show in the wrappanel !?

I would really appreciate some help and possibly a simple code example to help me on my way.

Comment: WPF by itself is a really complex framework and it requires a very specific mindset to work with (MVVM), which is very different from ancient traditional UI frameworks. My suggestion is you get familiar with C# itself before diving hard into WPF (maybe with some winforms or console applications?)

Comment: @HighCore Whoa, do my eyes deceive me?  You are recommending *something* in WinForms?

Comment: @LarsTech only for the beginners to get use to code, that's the ONLY thing that crap is actually valuable for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, Im using `UserControl`s instead of `Page`s to keep them in a single Window. Since you didn't post any XAML, I have no idea what your real need is, but here is my take:

MultiPageSample.xaml ("Main Window"):

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.MultiPageMVVM.MultiPageSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MiscSamples.MultiPageMVVM"
        Title="MultiPageSample" Height="300" Width="300">
    <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="2">
        <local:Page1 DataContext="{Binding Page1}"/>
        <local:Page2 DataContext="{Binding Page2}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MultiPageSample : Window
{
    public MultiPageSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MultiPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MultiPageViewModel
{
    public Page1ViewModel Page1 { get; set; }

    public Page2ViewModel Page2 { get; set; }

    public MultiPageViewModel()
    {
        Page1 = new Page1ViewModel();
        Page2 = new Page2ViewModel();

        Page2.AddNewCommand = new Command(Page1.AddCommand);
    }
}
```

Page1:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MiscSamples.MultiPageMVVM.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding}" Content="Click Me!"
                        Margin="2"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Page1 : UserControl
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Page2:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MiscSamples.MultiPageMVVM.Page2"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button Content="Add New Command (I Mean Button)"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Command="{Binding AddNewCommand}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Page2 : UserControl
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class Page2ViewModel
{
    public Command AddNewCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Command class (can be found on most MVVM frameworks)

```
//Dead-simple implementation of ICommand
    //Serves as an abstraction of Actions performed by the user via interaction with the UI (for instance, Button Click)
    public class Command : ICommand
    {
        public Action Action { get; set; }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (Action != null)
                Action();
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return IsEnabled;
        }

        private bool _isEnabled = true;
        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return _isEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                    CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public Command(Action action)
        {
            Action = action;
        }
    }

    public class Command<T>: ICommand
    {
        public Action<T> Action { get; set; }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (Action != null && parameter is T)
                Action((T)parameter);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return IsEnabled;
        }

        private bool _isEnabled;
        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return _isEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                    CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public Command(Action<T> action)
        {
            Action = action;
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Now, the explanation of all this mess:

First of all, you must [leave behind the traditional mentality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085) of *Manipulating UI elements in code*, and embrace [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137).

WPF has very powerful [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx) capabilities that are utterly absent in ancient dinosaur frameworks.

Notice how I'm using the reusable `Command` class (which is kind of a basic part of most MVVM frameworks) to represent the Buttons in the Page1ViewModel. These instances of `Command` are then added to the [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), which in turn notifies WPF when an element is added or removed to it, and thus the UI is automatically updated by the `Binding`.

Then, the [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) defined as the [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) for the [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) in `Page1` is used to "render" each item inside the `ObservableCollection`.

This is what I refer to when I say WPF needs a really different mindset to work with. This is the default approach to EVERYTHING in WPF. You almost NEVER have the need to reference / create / manipulate UI elements in procedural code. That's what XAML is for.

Also notice that this could be simplified A LOT by using the same `ViewModel` for both `Page`s, but I kept them separate on purpose just to show you this case where you have different ViewModels communicating with each other directly.

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Great thanks @HighCore!

You helped steer me in the right direction. Thanks for taking the time in crafting such a detailed reply.