# Why does binding of my ObservableCollection<string> to Listbox not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, mvvm-light

When I update a `ObservableCollection<string>` and call `RaisePropertyChanged(..)` somehow its content is not shown within my `Listbox` in WPF. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

The critical part is where I update the `FileNames` property:

```
public class HistoricalDataViewRawDataViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _currentDirectory;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _fileNames;
    private List<string> _rawData;

    public ICommand ChangeDirectoryCommand { get; private set; }
    public string CurrentDirectory
    {
        get { return _currentDirectory; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentDirectory != value)
            {
                _currentDirectory = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentDirectory");
            }
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> FileNames
    {
        get { return _fileNames; }
        set
        {
            if (_fileNames != value)
            {
                _fileNames = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FileNames");
            }
        }
    }

    public List<string> RawData
    {
        get { return _rawData; }
        set
        {
            if (_rawData != value)
            {
                _rawData = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("RawData");
            }
        }
    }

    public HistoricalDataViewRawDataViewModel()
    {
        ChangeDirectoryCommand = new RelayCommand(ChangeDirectory);
        var fileDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.HistoricalData_RawDataSourceDirectory;

        //set current directory
        CurrentDirectory = fileDirectory;

        //load all fileNames
        LoadAvailableFileNames(fileDirectory);
    }

    private void ChangeDirectory()
    {
        using (var folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            folderDialog.SelectedPath = CurrentDirectory;
            folderDialog.ShowDialog();

            //set current directory
            CurrentDirectory = folderDialog.SelectedPath;

            //save current directory to settings
            Properties.Settings.Default.HistoricalData_RawDataSourceDirectory = CurrentDirectory;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            //load files in chosen directory
            LoadAvailableFileNames(CurrentDirectory);
        }
    }

    private void LoadAvailableFileNames(string directory)
    {
        FileNames = new ObservableCollection<string>(FileIO.GetFileNamesInDirectory(directory, false, true));
    }
    private async void LoadRawData(string fileName)
    {

    }}
```

This is the xaml code. It should work as is because I look to display a `ObservableCollection<string>`. I added couple items to the listbox from code-behind and it displayed just fine:

```
DataContext="{Binding HistoricalDataViewRawDataViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ToggleButton Margin="10"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Choose Directory" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Command="{Binding ChangeDirectoryCommand}"/>
        <TextBlock 
            Margin="10"
            FontSize="18"
            Foreground="White"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            TextAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding CurrentDirectory}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <dxdo:DockLayoutManager Grid.Row="1">

        <dxdo:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical">

            <dxdo:LayoutPanel ItemHeight="7*">
                <dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
                    <ListBox Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding FileNames}"/>
                </dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
            </dxdo:LayoutPanel>

            <dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="Activity Log" ItemHeight="200" >
                <dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
                    <ListBox/>
                </dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
            </dxdo:LayoutPanel>

        </dxdo:LayoutGroup>

    </dxdo:DockLayoutManager>

</Grid>
```

Comment: @GrantWinney, why would it? I do not even bind `RawData`. But I changed it for the fun of it, no change.

Comment: List<string>? FileNames is a ObservableCollection<string> not List<string>. I assume your DataContext is not set correctly, which brakes your binding in ItemsSource="{Binding FileNames}. Can you show where you set your datacontext?

Comment: @user1182735, datacontext is set correctly, I see the reference to `FileNames` in my viewmodel. But I added the xaml code line as well

Comment: @GrantWinney, fair comment, I am concerned with `FileNames`. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: May I suggest that you create a [*minimal* example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Apparently, neither `RawData` nor the fact that the entries are file names have anything to do with the core of the problem. And the reliance on some `dxdo:` namespace prevents others from trying to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @dkozl, what is not clear? I am happy to edit my question, but I never said it deals with files, it is an `ObservableCollection<string>` that and I want its content shown in a listbox. Something that takes 10 seconds in Winforms is causing major headache while learning WPF. Thanks

Comment: @dkozl, yes I use the exact same approach in other views/viewmodels. Basically a ViewModelLocator wrapped around a ServiceLocator. By the way the Binding of `CurrentDirectory` to my textblock works just fine, which means that the correct viewmodel instance is perused.

Comment: Instead of using another method to set the property you could initialize FileNames directly from the c'tor. Just to see whether the binding is working at all. In c'tor: FileNames = new ObservableCollection<string>{"a", "b", "c"}; If this works, try to update the existing ObservableCollection<string> instance with clear and add/insert instead of setting a new one.

Comment: @user1182735, I tried that already, no luck. Either the binding is not working or the content has to be specially formatted via DataTemplate (though I hope not on a simple `string` collection).

Comment: Can you set the datacontext directly on the ListBox? <ListBox Name="MyListBox" DataContext="{Binding HistoricalDataViewRawDataViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" ItemsSource="{Binding FileNames}"/>. If this works, than this indicates  that the inhitance context is broken.

Comment: @user1182735, now this worked, and I am totally at a loss of ideas why. As you can see in my xaml code the datacontext for the textblock and togglebutton works perfectly fine. Could you pls elaborate what you mean with "inheritance context broken"?

Comment: I assume these dxdo-controls are non-standard controls? I assume these controls break the inheritance mechanism. The inheritance mechanism applies to all FrameworkElement objects. It means that the property values are inherited along the logical tree. This enables you to set the datacontext property on the outer Grid but use it, for example, on the TextBlock. The value that you set on the Grid is inherited by the StackPanel and then again by the TextBlock. This only works for objects that inherit from FrameworkElement.

Comment: @user1182735, OMG, this is driving me insane. How can one reliably learn and code WPF if it takes heavy bug fixes and broken user controls (this is DevEx controls and not the first bug I had to deal with in this one week of learning WPF). It really wants me to go back to Winforms where things were more basic but rock solid. But I wonder, the listbox here is a standard windows control. I am quite frustrated to be honest and its only my 1st week into xaml and WPF...

Comment: See it from the positive side. You are only developing wpf for one week and already know about the inheritance context. It took me 2 years to get there ;) Try to find out if these dxdo-classes are deriving from FrameworkElement.

Comment: ok, will try to dig into that a little more. Thanks for pointing me into that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this support ticket](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T175670) in DevExpress, simply removing the `LayoutControlItem` works.

I created a sample project using your XAML and some dummy data and it works fine:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dxdo="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <dxdo:DockLayoutManager Grid.Row="1">

        <dxdo:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical">

            <dxdo:LayoutPanel ItemHeight="7*">
                <!-- notice the removal of LayoutControlItem here -->
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileNames}"/>
            </dxdo:LayoutPanel>

            <dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="Activity Log" ItemHeight="200" >
                <ListBox/>
            </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
        </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
    </dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Dummy data
        DataContext = new
        {
            FileNames = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(x => "File" + x.ToString())
        };
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: As a side note: you need [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) like water when working with WPF (at least until VS 2015 is released with similar capabilities).

Comment: As a side note 2: your `ObservableCollection`s should be read-only properties ( `{get {....}}`) and be instantiated only once in the VMs constructor. That way to reduce a little bit of code and guarantee you're always binding against the correct collection.

Comment: awesome that did the trick. I actually changed the string collection to a `List<string>` because I never change individual elements inside the collection, each time a completely new collection is bound [I followed your advice and rather clear the existing list and add via `AddRange`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume these dxdo-controls are non-standard controls? I assume these controls break the inheritance mechanism. The inheritance mechanism applies to all FrameworkElement objects. It means that the property values are inherited along the logical tree. This enables you to set the datacontext property on the outer Grid but use it, for example, on the TextBlock. The value that you set on the Grid is inherited by the StackPanel and then again by the TextBlock. This only works for objects that inherit from FrameworkElement.

Can you set the datacontext directly on the ListBox? . If this works, than this indicates that the inhitance context is broken.

Comment: it works but how can the data context be broken if a few lines above the same datacontext for `textblock` and `button` works just fine?

Comment: Inheritance of the DataContext value works along the logical tree. Textblock is child of StackPanel which child of Grid which is Child of whatever. These are all FrameworkElements, which means they support the inheritance mechanism. Your ListBox is child of LayoutControlItem which is child of LayoutPanel which is child of LayoutGroup which is child of DockLayoutManager. I do not know whether these DevEx-elements support property inheritance. It looks like they do not.

Comment: Ah that makes much more sense now. Thanks I will check, maybe I can get away with declaring datacontext higher up in the "chain" if I can identify the one that does not correctly inherit.

Comment: You can also use other workarounds: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27432/Artificial-Inheritance-Contexts-in-WPF. This is advanced wpf. good luck!

Comment: thanks for your help. It appeared that a  `DX LayoutControlItem` caused issues.