# What is WPF equivalent of Windows Forms Region.Xor in Paint event?

Tags: c#, c, wpf, paint, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to move this WinForms code to WPF, but there is no `Paint` event.

```
private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var region = new Region(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
    region.Xor(rectangle);
    e.Graphics.FillRegion(Brushes.Black, region);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have edited your code so that it displays correctly.

Comment: Please read [Rachel's Excellent Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085) of what's required when upgrading from winforms to WPF.

Answer (score 1):

WPF doesn't work like WinForms in terms of graphics. You can't actually draw shapes, you have to place them into your content.

[`Geometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx) should serve as a good replacement for `Region`. You can use [`Geometry.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms607449.aspx) and specify [`GeometryCombineMode.Xor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrycombinemode.aspx) to replicate your drawing code.

[`RectangleGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rectanglegeometry.aspx) is how you make rectangles. There are similar classes for other shapes.

To actually display the `Geometry`, put it in a [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx), which can be used as a control's content.