# How do you use a webbrowser control for styling but have the logic in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, user-interface

I have seen a few applications do this. They use HTML/CSS/Javascript for the styling (which is a million times easier than creating the same thing natively), but they have the logic of the program in C#, I have no idea how to interconnect the two. I was trying to google around, but I couldn't find anything with my phrasing. Any quick explanation or example would be awesome!

Thanks,
Jon

EDIT: As clarification (sorry) I mean a desktop application built with something like C# or C++ or something of the like

Comment: like an ASP.NET website?

Comment: Sorry I edited it, I meant to say it is for a desktop application

Comment: I think you've been looking at WPF applications, which use XAML.  Did it resemble [code like this?](http://wpftutorial.net/XAML.html)

Comment: Is WPF a good way to build completely custom UI's? For example http://puu.sh/4BCd0.jpg - which is a custom game launcher client. I want to be able to make something comparable to that.

Comment: @dibesjr if you doubt WPF's capabilities, check the last link in my answer.

Comment: Yes. WPF = Jennifer Lawrence

Comment: What is a good resource to get started making custom UI's in WPF? For example off of a PSD or some graphical resource?

Comment: @dibesjr WPF is vector graphics, the tool you use to create custom controls is either Blend or Visual Studio, or you can also import other vector graphic formats into Blend or something.

Answer (score 2):

First create a ComVisible class

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class JSObject
{
    public void ShowMessage(string s)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}
```

Then set WebBrowser control's `ObjectForScripting` property

```
webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new JSObject();
```

Set html content

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"
                      <script>
                          external.ShowMessage('test'); 
                          function ShowIt(s){alert(s);} 
                      </script>";
```

and call in Javascript C#'s `ShowMessage` method

And this the the other way,,

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
          webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("ShowIt",new object[]{"test2"});
    };
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is a viable solution. How is anyone supposed to create a professional application using such a rudimentary technique? javascript as a `string`? Are you serious? method names as strings too? and parameters?

Comment: @HighCore Whether you like it or not. As OP requested, It  shows the interaction between javascript and c# .

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms754130.aspx).

It uses [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) for the UI and styling, while allowing you to create the application logic in pure C# or any .Net language.

it is the replacement of winforms, which is a really old technology no one cares about anymore, and which doesn't support anything.

WPF brings the flexibility and declarative paradigm of the Web into the Windows Desktop.

It goes hand and hand with a new development paradigm called [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085), which you need to learn if you want to create [**Professional Looking, Awesome Windows Applications**](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/)

Don't try to hack something together by trying to put a `WebBrowser` or anything like that in a Windows Application. The Web is the Web and Desktop is Desktop.