# How to Programmatically create Grid within row of a Grid in Wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am working in WPF -- There is `button` with `click event handler` in my application. As i click on button it's event handler generates a new row in grid named as `grids`. In this new Row i want to add another grid programmatically to add Label, Button and TextBox in this grid in row.
As i executed my code it only generates a texboxes! where labels and button shown once! Here code and image is : *Please feel free to ask if my query is not clear to you!*

```
 int r =0;
 private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextEdit text1; Button button1; Grid grid1;
        grids.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        text1 = new TextEdit();
        text1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
        text1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, r);
        button1 = new Button();
        button1.Content = "Left + " + r;
        button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click);
        button1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
        button1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, r);
        grid1 = new Grid();
        grid1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
        grids.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, r);
        grids.Children.Add(button1);
        grids.Children.Add(text1);
        r = r + 1;
    }
```

[image]
**EDIT**

```
 int r =0;
 private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    db obj = new db();
    var query = from p in obj.TableA select p ;

  foreach(var a in query.ToList())
  {
    TextEdit text1; Button button1; Grid grid1;
    grids.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    text1 = new TextEdit();
    text1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
    text1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, r);
    button1 = new Button();
    button1.Content = a.name;
    button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click);
    button1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
    button1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, r);
    grid1 = new Grid();
    grid1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
    grids.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    grid1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, r);
    grids.Children.Add(button1);
    grids.Children.Add(text1);
    r = r + 1;}
}
```

Comment: You should use `StackPanel` instead of `Grid` as the outer layout

Comment: @Anirudh ok thank's should i have to add this stackpanel in grid1?

Comment: Grid with name `grids` should be a `stackpanel` which would then contain all the grids..

Comment: can you not nest a grid in a grid

Comment: @GeorgianBrit then what to do :(

Comment: you need to add a namer that increments i.e. text1, text2, etc and loop it

Comment: @GeorgianBrit actually i am retrieving their contents from database

Comment: can you show me the code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38289/discussion-between-tameen-malik-and-georgianbrit)

Comment: Here is your misprint: grids.Children.Add(button1); grids.Children.Add(text1); You should do like this: grid1.Children.Add(button1); grid1.Children.Add(text1); grids.Children.Add(grid1);

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok. Delete all your code and start all over.

If you're working with WPF, you really need to have [**The WPF Mentality**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085)

As a general rule, you almost **never** create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF.
That's what XAML is for.

This the right way to do what you're asking in WPF (in a full working example):

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.ItemsControlSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
        Title="ItemsControlSample" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button Content="Add New Row" Command="{Binding AddNewRowCommand}"
                DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border  BorderBrush="Black" Background="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2">
                        <!-- This is the Inner Grid for each element, which is represented in Brown color in your picture -->
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Content="{Binding Label1Text}"
                                   Margin="2"/>

                            <Button Content="Button1" 
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.Command1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                    Grid.Column="1" Margin="2"/>

                            <Button Content="Button2" 
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.Command2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                    Grid.Column="2" Margin="2"/>

                            <dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding Text}"
                                          Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                          Margin="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class ItemsControlSample : Window
{
    public ItemsControlSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ItemsControlSampleViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ItemsControlSampleViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemsControlSampleData> Data { get; set; }

    public Command AddNewRowCommand { get; set; }

    public Command<ItemsControlSampleData> Command1 { get; set; }

    public Command<ItemsControlSampleData> Command2 { get; set; }

    public ItemsControlSampleViewModel()
    {
        var sampledata = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                                   .Select(x => new ItemsControlSampleData()
                                                {
                                                    Label1Text = "Label1 " + x.ToString(),
                                                    Text = "Text" + x.ToString()
                                                });

        Data = new ObservableCollection<ItemsControlSampleData>(sampledata);
        AddNewRowCommand = new Command(AddNewRow);
        Command1 = new Command<ItemsControlSampleData>(ExecuteCommand1);
        Command2 = new Command<ItemsControlSampleData>(ExecuteCommand2);

    }

    private void AddNewRow()
    {
        Data.Add(new ItemsControlSampleData() {Label1Text = "Label 1 - New Row", Text = "New Row Text"});
    }

    private void ExecuteCommand1(ItemsControlSampleData data)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Command1 - " + data.Label1Text);
    }

    private void ExecuteCommand2(ItemsControlSampleData data)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Command2 - " + data.Label1Text);
    }
}
```

Data Item:

```
public class ItemsControlSampleData
{
    public string Label1Text { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Helper classes:

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    public Action Action { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (Action != null)
            Action();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return IsEnabled;
    }

    private bool _isEnabled = true;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            _isEnabled = value;
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public Command(Action action)
    {
        Action = action;
    }
}

public class Command<T>: ICommand
{
    public Action<T> Action { get; set; }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (Action != null && parameter is T)
            Action((T)parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return IsEnabled;
    }

    private bool _isEnabled = true;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            _isEnabled = value;
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public Command(Action<T> action)
    {
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

- Notice how I'm not dealing with UI in procedural code, but instead I'm using [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and *simple, simple properties*. That's how you program in WPF. That's what the WPF mentality is about.
- I'm using an [ItemsControl](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) and a [DataTemplate](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/01/03/itemscontrol-d-is-for-datatemplate/) defined in XAML to let WPF create the UI for each of my data items.
- Also notice how my code does nothing except expose the data and define reusable [Commands](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) that serve as abstractions to the user actions such as Button clicks. This way you can concentrate in coding your business  logic instead of struggling with how to make the UI work.
- The buttons inside each item are bound to the Commands using a [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553635(v=vs.95).aspx) Binding to navigate upwards in the Visual Tree and find the DataContext of the ItemsControl, where the Commands are actually defined.
- When you need to add a new item, you just add a new item to the `ObservableCollection` that contains your data and WPF automatically creates the new UI elements bound to that.
- Though this might seem like "too much code", most of the code I posted here is highly reusable and can be implemented in a Generic `ViewModel<T>` that is then reusable for any type of data items. `Command` and `Command<T>` are also write-once reusable classes that can be found in any MVVM framework such as [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/), [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) or [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/).
- This approach is really much preferred in WPF, because it enables a great amount of scalability and independence between the UI and the business logic, and it also enables testability of the ViewModel.
- I suggest you read all the materials linked in the post, most importantly Rachel's WPF Mentality and related blog posts. Let me know if you need further help.
- **WPF Rocks**. Just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself.

Comment: High Core ! is it possible to do this without MVVM use?

Comment: @tameenmalik why would you do that? MVVM goes hand and hand with WPF. Doing Non-MVVM WPF is really looking for uneeded trouble.

Comment: Yes HighCore you are Right :) . . . but actually i want this :( :)

Comment: @Tameenmalik I'm afraid I will not be able to help you with that. Writing unnecessary, ugly, unmaintainable code is not my area.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

It's actually much easier in behind code then in xaml code..

My Xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAddGridWithStackPanel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="Grid_Grid" Margin="0,0,0,32">

        <Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="Grid_Grid" Margin="0,0,0,32"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button x:Name="btn_Add" Height="32" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Add New Row" Click="btn_Add_Click" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
    <Button x:Name="btn_Remove" Height="32" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Remove last Row" Click="btn_Remove_Click" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int num = 0;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void btn_Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Grid_Grid.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(Grid_Grid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
                Grid_Grid.Children.RemoveAt(Grid_Grid.Children.Count - 1);
                num--;
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
            DockPanel dock = new DockPanel();
            Label lbl = new Label();
            Button btn1 = new Button();
            Button btn2 = new Button();
            TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();

            stack.Children.Add(dock);
            stack.Children.Add(txt1);
            dock.Children.Add(lbl);
            dock.Children.Add(btn2);
            dock.Children.Add(btn1);

            #region StackPanel Properties
            stack.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            #endregion

            #region DockPanel Content Properties
            lbl.Content = "Label " + (num + 1).ToString();
            lbl.Height = 32;
            lbl.Width = 100;
            lbl.FontSize = 12;
            lbl.SetValue(DockPanel.DockProperty, Dock.Left);
            lbl.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;

            btn1.Content = "Butten 1";
            btn1.Height = 32;
            btn1.Width = 100;
            btn1.FontSize = 12;
            btn1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            btn1.SetValue(DockPanel.DockProperty, Dock.Right);
            btn1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn1_Click);

            btn2.Content = "Butten 2";
            btn2.Height = 32;
            btn2.Width = 100;
            btn2.FontSize = 12;
            btn2.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            btn2.SetValue(DockPanel.DockProperty, Dock.Right);
            btn2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn2_Click);
            #endregion

            #region TextBox Properties
            txt1.Text = "Text " + (num + 1).ToString();
            txt1.Height = 32;
            txt1.Width = double.NaN;
            txt1.FontSize = 12;
            txt1.Padding = new Thickness(0, 7, 0, 7);
            #endregion

            Grid_Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            Grid_Grid.RowDefinitions[num].Height = new GridLength(66, GridUnitType.Pixel);
            Grid_Grid.Children.Add(stack);
            stack.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, num);
            num++;
        }
    }
```