# How to attach extra data to listbox items in VB.Net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

i'm new to visual studio and working on a project in visual basic. I am additing data to listbox from database that i need to access later.. Can we add extra data to listbox items as we can do with following html ??

```
<option name="harry" age="10" value="1">My name is harry</option>
```

any ideas please ???

regards

Comment: If you're working with WPF, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "attach" any data (whatever that means) to any UI elements in WPF, simply because [**UI is not Data**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085).

If you're working with WPF, you really need to understand [**The WPF Mentality**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085), which is very different from other approaches used in other technologies.

In WPF, you use [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) to "Bind" the UI to the Data, as opposed to "putting" or "storing" the data in the UI.

This is an example of how you Bind a `ListBox` to a collection of data items in WPF:

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyData> MyCollection {get;set;}

    //methods to create and populate the collection.
}
```

Data Item:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string LastName {get;set;}

    public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

I strongly suggest that you read up on MVVM before starting to code in WPF. Otherwise you'll hit walls quickly and waste too much time in unneeded code.