# WPF Keep the UI responsive while wait for the user's choice

Tags: wpf, vb.net, vb6-migration

I have this code in VB.Net, in windows forms. I need to wait for the user's choice, but keeping the UI responsive, so the user can select a option from a ListBox. The listbox_SelectionChanged event will set a Boolean named selectedElement to true, so the execution continues. In WPF I have found that it is possible to do it with threading but I am not sure how to do it. Any advice? Thanks :)

```
    Do
       System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Loop Until selectedElement
```

Comment: What are you waiting on that is blocking the UI? what is blocking the UI

Comment: `DoEvents()` is evil. even in winforms. Post the relevant code that keeps executing and blocking the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a terribly bad way to code. Even in winforms.

First of all, if you're working in WPF you really need to understand [**The WPF Mentality**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085).

in MVVM WPF, your `ViewModel` should control the actions executed by the application upon reacting to user input.

Generally speaking, this is how you deal with "wait for the user to select an item in a `ListBox` in WPF:

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeData> SomeCollection {get;set;}

    //Methods to instantiate and populate the Collection.

    private SomeData _selectedItem;
    public SomeData SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            //PropertyChanged() is probably desired here.

            UserHasSelectedAnItem(); //Method invocation
        }
    }

    private void UserHasSelectedAnItem()
    {
       //Actions after the user has selected an item
    }
}
```

Notice how this is fundamentally different from the `RefreshTheUIHack();` loop approach.

There's no need to "loop" anything because WPF (and also winforms) already have an internal
"message loop" which listens for user input and raises events when needed.

I suggest you read the above linked answer and related blog posts to understand what you need in order to move from the traditional, procedural winforms approach into the DataBinding-based WPF mentality.