# WPF C# : How to get the content size and location dynamically on TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

In WindowsAPI, TabControl can calculate the (non-tab) client-area by AdjustRect command.

I want to calculate the (tabpage, not tabitem) tab control area in WPF.

How should I do?

**XAML**
<sub>MainWindow.xaml</sub>

```
...
<Grid>
  <TabControl x:Name="tabcontrol"/>
  <Button x:Name="outercontrol"/>
</Grid>
...
```

**C#**
<sub>MainWindow.xaml.cs</sub>

```
void Add(SomeObject obj)
{
  TabItem item = new TabItem() { Header = obj.Text, Tag = obj };
  tabcontrol.Items.Add(item);
  RepositionControl();
}

void RepositionControl()
{
  var margin = CalculateTabPageContentArea(); // like this...
  this.outercontrol.Margin = margin;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want such a thing? You should let WPF manage content positioning except in the most extreme customization cases. Usually it is possible to do what's required with a couple of grids, borders and wrap panels.

Comment: Because I want to use only single control. By default, inner tabcontrols need multi controls. I don't want this situation.

Comment: In code behind , you can get this.tabcontrol  ActualWidth and ActualHeight , 
is that what your looking for ?

Comment: Wat. A tabcontrol does not need multi controls. If you have your own switching mechanism, or if your tabs control something other than visibilities of collections of controls, don't put anything into tabs' content. Instead, just bind to tab control's SelectedItem property.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. WPF is fundamentally different from anything else. You can't bend WPF to your will, you need to bend your will to WPF. Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code. That's what XAML is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I see you're fundamentally wrong in almost everything you're thinking about WPF and how it works.

First of all, WPF is fundamentally different from any other technologies. 
If you're working with WPF, you really need to leave behind all the horrendous HACKS you might be used to from ancient technologies and embrace [**The WPF Mentality**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085).

WPF UIs are composed of a [Visual Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx) where all visual elements are placed in a hierarchical manner. Therefore it can be said that all UI elements (except the top-most `Window`) may have a *Visual Parent* and one or more *Visual Children*.

WPF also introduces the concept of [ControlTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx), which allows you to define the visual structure and appearance of any given Control without losing it's behavior and without resorting to horrible procedural practices such as "owner draw".

Given this, the [WPF Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx) takes care of placing UI elements in their correct position "inside" their containing parent, taking into account several properties such as `Template`, `Margin`, `VerticalAlignment`, `HorizontalAlignment`, `Width` and `Height`.

Keep in mind that [WPF is Resolution Independent](http://www.wpflearningexperience.com/?p=41), therefore most of the time you will NOT want to give a fixed size and position to UI elements, leaving the Layout System the freedom to adjust them to the available screen or parent Window size when the user resizes the Window.

*Notice how this is a much better approach from the traditional, horrible winforms approach, where you would hard code all element sizes and therefore had to support only a specific window size.*

Let's have a look at the Visual Tree of a `TabControl` with 2 `TabItem`s using the [Default TabControl Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.TabControlSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TabControlSample" Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="Window">
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 1">
            <TextBlock Text="Tab Content 1" x:Name="TabContent1"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab Item 2">
            <TextBlock Text="Tab Content 2" x:Name="TabContent2"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image]

Using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) or a similar spy tool, we can see the following Visual Tree generated by the above XAML:

[image]

First thing you notice here is that there is a LOT more going on than just `TabItem`s and `TextBlock`s, which is what we defined in XAML. That's because of the ControlTemplates, which define the internal Visual Tree of any given Control.

This is the main reason for which you're not supposed to bother WPF with any procedural hacks, and instead let it do it's work, which it does pretty well.

I suggest you start by reading the above linked "WPF Mentality" post and [this introduction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start) to WPF layouts.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: WPF system consists of hierarchical controls... I see. Thanks.