# Reused DataGrid control values repeat

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, virtualization

The problem is, when I edit programmatically column values in datagrid and scroll down, those values repeat in next cells of column which become visible. This seems like virtualization bug or "effect" since when I switch it off, problem disappears. I think the problem is in this place:

```
public void EditedCell(object oItem, string oColumnName, ref List<string> lErrors, object newValue = null)
{
    DataGridRow dgRow = dgDati.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(oItem) as DataGridRow;
    /* In other places, when I call EditedCell(DataGridRow, ...) it works fine.
       The problem shows up only when I call EditedCell(object oItem, ...) */
    EditedCell(dgRow, oColumnName, ref lErrors, newValue);
}
```

This is the screen of problem. Yellow cells are programmatically changed and other 0000 containing cells are shown due to this problem. When I read data from DataSource it doesnt have those 0000 values in DataRows:

[image]

Also to set value of cell, I set cell controls in cell and DataRow value to change value and display it properly:

```
if (oElement.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
{
    (oElement as TextBox).Text = newValue.ToString();
}

if (oElement.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
{
    (oElement as TextBlock).Text = newValue.ToString();
}
```

Have anyone seen anything similar and knows how to deal with that?

Comment: Quoting @HighCore's clincher - "Don't manipulate WPF control's through procedural code" :) [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) will save you all this headache

Comment: As @Omribitan has quietly hinted, manipulating UI controls programmatically is *not* the WPF way. In general, we `Bind` to the UI controls and manipulate the data instead... you'll get *far* fewer problems doing it this way.

Comment: @Omribitan Thanks for spreading the word =). Now I know I'm not alone.

Comment: @Omribitan yeah, i did something along MVVM way and it worked. Please post some sort of an answer so I can approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't manipulate WPF control's through procedural code. This is not the [WPF way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681352/transitioning-from-windows-forms-to-wpf/15684569#15684569). In WPF you should manipulate your data which is binded to the UI, instead of manipulating the UI directly. This design pattern is known as [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and will spare you all this headache.