# Datagrid in WPF C#. How to add custom values to each cells in a row

Tags: c#, wpf

I have three textboxes. I need to add each value to the corresponding fields. Datagrid have headers "#, ProductName, ProductCode, Tax, Total"

WPF

```
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding dt}" x:Name="dgrdBilling" MinColumnWidth="100" Grid.Row="1" CanUserReorderColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" Margin="1,0,-1,0">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Width="25" CanUserResize="False" MinWidth="25"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"/>
                        <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=ProductName}"/>-->
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tax1"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tax2"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tax3"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Click Event of button to add data to datagrid

```
    private void btnAddProduct_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Products_Master WHERE ProductName =('" + txtAutoProductName.Text + "') OR ProductCode = ('" + txtProductCode.Text + "')", con);
        try
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dg = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid();
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
            da.SelectCommand = com;
            da.Fill(dt);
            bSource.DataSource = dt;
            dg.Items.Add(txtAutoProductName.Text);
            dg.Items.Add(txtAutoProductCode.Text);
            dg.Items.Add(txtQuantity.Text);
            //dgrdBilling.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            //dgrdBilling.Items.Add(dg);
            da.Update(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're creating one `DataGrid` in XAML, and another `DataGrid` in code-behind. Which one you want to be filled with data?

Comment: ohh sorry. Is that what happening there. I don't know. I just need to add datarow wise after pressing the button each time.

Comment: You shouldn't manipulate UI from code-behind in WPF. You should have a proper data type containing the `ProductName, ProductCode, Tax, Total` field, fill a collection of that type from your DB, and bind the `DataGrid` to that.

Comment: BTW, You should alter your SQL tatement to use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) to avoid SQL injection

Comment: How is it done, to avoid SQL injection?

Comment: Look at the link in my previous comment. There is a detailed example on the MSDN page.

Comment: Are you using MVVM or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Seem like you confused a lot of stuff here.

First of all, you shouldn't manipulate UI Elements from code-behind in WPF. You should have a proper data type containing the ProductName, ProductCode, Tax, Total or any other fields you may want, fill a collection of that type, and bind THAT to the `DataGrid`.

```
public class Product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    public int Tax { get; set; }

    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

Store a collection of that class (preferably `ObservableCollection` that notifys the UI when it changes to make it update itself)

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set;}
```

Usually it should be done in different class that you set as the `DataContext` of the window (Known as *ViewModel*), But if you set it in the code-behind, you can just set the window's `DataContext` to itself. In window's constructor after `InitializeComponents()` add

```
DataContext = this
```

Now, create a `Product` with the relevant data and add it to the collection instead of directly to the grid:

```
        Product p = new Product
        {
            ProductName = txtAutoProductName.Text,
            ProductCode = txtAutoProductCode.Text
            // Fill in the rest of the properties as you want ...
        }
        Products.Add(p);
```

Finally, Alter your grid to look something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" x:Name="dgrdBilling" MinColumnWidth="100" Grid.Row="1" CanUserReorderColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" Margin="1,0,-1,0">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Width="25" CanUserResize="False" MinWidth="25"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding ProductName}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding ProductCode}"/>
                    <!-- rest of your columns ... -->
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

To are some links that can help you understand the concept better:

[Transitioning from Windows Forms to WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681352/transitioning-from-windows-forms-to-wpf)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140621/WPF-Tutorial-Concept-Binding

Also you should look into the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern which is considered the best practice when developing WPF application

Good luck

Comment: If you don't mind can u explain what "Products" means in <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" x:Name="dgrdBilling"

Comment: The `ItemsSource` should be binded to a collection (a class that implements the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface). as you can see in my example, `Products` is actually property of type `ObservableCollection<T>` in that class defined as `DataContext` (In this example, the same class where you handle the button's click event hence you set `DataContext = this`). The `DataGrid` Iterates the collection and add's each element as a row. this is why you should manipulate DATA (the collection) and let WPF do the rest of the work.

Comment: Also, to make the `DataGrid` update each time we change it's underlying collection, we need to raise an event called `PropertyChanged` every time we change the colleciton. The reason I said "preferably ObservableCollection" is because it already implements this for us.

Comment: "public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set;}" It causes an error. The type or namespace name 'ObservableCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to add the following using statement `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;`

Comment: I am getting an exception at Products.Add(p);. Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40158/discussion-between-kamal-mohan-and-omribitan)

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN You need to initialize it first `Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();`

Comment: The datagrid is still blank.

Comment: yes @Kamal is right, i still dont see the `DataGrid`

Comment: can anyone guide  me why?

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding bindings in WPF and mixing WinForms and WPF binding approach.

First of all, `DataGrid` supports direct binding to a `DataTable` instance, so, it is enough to set `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to a `DataTable`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomDataTable}">
```

The second, `DataGrid` by default can generate columns from `DataTable` schema. If you want to override this behavior, you should turn off column generation (this is done in your code), and, also, you should bind your columns with `DataTable` columns like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyHeader" Binding="{Binding MyDataTableColumnName}"/>
```

The third, you don't want to add a row to the `DataGrid`. You want to a row to the `DataTable`, so, your click handler should look like this:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        dataTable.Rows.Add(/* ... */);
    }
```