# Clicking a Uniformgrid filled with grids, getting name of the grid im clicking

Tags: c#, wpf, uniformgrid

im new to WPF and im using this code to fill a uniformgrid with grids,

```
 public MainWindow()  
                {  
                    InitializeComponent();  
                    SolidColorBrush defaultBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Wheat);  
                    SolidColorBrush alternateBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                    Char L = 'A';
                    int N = 1;  
                    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)  
                    {  
                        Grid cell = new Grid();
                        if(N==9)
                         {   
                            N=1;
                            L++;
                         }

                        if ((i + i / 8) % 2 == 0)  
                        {  
                            cell.Name = L + N.ToString();
                            cell.Background = defaultBrush;  
                            ChessBoard.Children.Add(cell);  
                        }  
                        else  
                        {  
                            cell.Name = L + N.ToString();
                            cell.Background = alternateBrush;   
                            ChessBoard.Children.Add(cell);  
                        } 
                        N++
                    }
```

im then trying to find out what name a certain grid has when i click down on the uniformedgrid called ChessBoard.

```
       private void ChessBoard_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
        {


            var element = (UIElement)args.Source;
            element.Opacity = 0.5; 
        }
```

the opacity line is test to make sure im on the right grid, and it works and changs the Opacity of the grid im clicking.

What i need help with is to find the Name attribute of the element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, delete all your code and start all over.

If you're working with WPF, you really need to understand and embrace [**The WPF Mentality**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085).

As a general rule, creating or manipulating UI elements in procedural code is discouraged.
Instead, you create a proper [ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085) which will hold all the relevant properties that represent the state and data shown by the UI, and use [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) to reflect these properties.

This is how you do what you're trying here, in WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="ChessBoardSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="350">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="8" Columns="8"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button x:Name="Square"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.SquareClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>

                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBlack}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Square" Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBlack}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Square" Property="Background" Value="Wheat"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ChessBoard();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ChessBoard
{
    public List<ChessSquare> Squares { get; private set; }

    public Command<ChessSquare> SquareClickCommand { get; private set; }

    public ChessBoard()
    {
        Squares = new List<ChessSquare>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                Squares.Add(new ChessSquare() {Row = i, Column = j});
            }
        }

        SquareClickCommand = new Command<ChessSquare>(OnSquareClick);
    }

    private void OnSquareClick(ChessSquare square)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked on Row: " + square.Row + " - Column: " + square.Column);
    }
}
```

Data Item:

```
public class ChessSquare
{
    public int Row { get; set; }

    public int Column { get; set; }

    public bool IsBlack { get { return (Row + Column) %2 == 1; }}        
}
```

Command class (MVVM helper class):

```
public class Command<T>: ICommand
{
    public Action<T> Action { get; set; }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (Action != null && parameter is T)
            Action((T)parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return IsEnabled;
    }

    private bool _isEnabled = true;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            _isEnabled = value;
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public Command(Action<T> action)
    {
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

- While all this might look like "too much code", If you look closely you'll realize that most of it is actually reusable, clean code with no dependencies on the UI, and I'm also giving you a lot of reusable infrastructure (such as the `Command` class).
- I'm using an [`ItemsControl`](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) bound to a collection of Data Items, rather than creating the UI elements procedurally. This is "letting WPF do it's job".
- The main idea is to *Separate UI and Logic*, thus gaining a LOT of scalability and maintainability.
- Notice how the code behind is reduced to a mere `DataContext = ...`. Code behind in WPF is reserved for **UI Specific** code, rather than code related to data or logic.
- I'm using a [`DelegateCommand`](http://relentlessdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/simplified-mvvm-commanding-with-delegatecommand/) to handle the Click logic, rather than an event handler. This is useful in situations where UI elements are being created dynamically by an ItemsControl and the like.
- Also notice how the `OnSquareClick()` method is operating against your own simple, stateful data item (`ChessSquare`) rather than complex arcane WPF UI objects. That's how you program in WPF. You operate against your data, not the UI.
- Also notice the usage of a [DataTrigger](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/triggers/) against the `IsBlack` property, to dynamically change the background color.
- **WPF Rocks**. Just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for youself.
- I strongly suggest you read all the linked material. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks alot for the response! will take a look and start from scratch!

Comment: After some reading now i have managed to get a good grip on this, the only problem i have so far are the command, I have read though the DelegateCommand link you gave me and watched some youtube guides but still face problems with the command you showed me.

Do i have to define ICommand some way, or how does that work in your example?

Comment: @Martin the [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) interface is defined in `System.Windows.Input`.