# WPF how to get selected tab colour in a tab item

Tags: c#, wpf, selected, tabitem, systemcolors

How can I get the selected colour in a tabitem?

[image]

I want to use it to change the background:

```
t.Background = new SolidColorBrush(SystemColors.WindowColor);
```

and have tried all possibilities but didn't get the right one

[image]

Comment: Take a look on [WPF TabControl, change the background color of the TabItem with C# codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555505/wpf-tabcontrol-change-the-background-color-of-the-tabitem-with-c-sharp-codes), I think it will help.

Comment: I am not clear at what has this got to do with my problem: here it says how to set tab colour with some predefined colours. Instead I want to know what is the predefined tab colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Brush brsTabSelected = default(Brush);
private void WindowViewBase_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  tabItem1.IsSelected = true;
  brsTabSelected = tabItem1.Background;
}
```