# Looping with Wpf tabitem Controls using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, recursion

Hi i am famliar with windows forms, Now i am going to start WPF, in windows i reset the controls with the following recursive method

```
 internal  void clrCntrls(Control cntrl)
    {
        if (cntrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            TextBox cntrl = (TextBox)cntrl;
            cntrl.Text = "";               
        }            
         else if (cntrl.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
        {
            ComboBox cntrl = (ComboBox)cntrl;
            cntrl.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Control subCntrl in _cntrl.Controls)
            {
                clrCntrls(subCntrl);
            }
        }
```

it works fine for me in windows but the same how can i do in WPF. i am slight Confusion with that. Please help with it.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to clear the data in the controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `VisualTreeHelper`, but it'll only work for controls that are currently in the visual tree, i.e. rendered. If you have a `TabControl` you won't get access to controls on a `TabItem` that is not selected at the moment.

Here's a quick attempt at it:

```
private void ClearControls(DependencyObject root)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root); i++)
    {
        var control = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);

        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            (control as TextBox).Text = String.Empty;
        }
        else if (control is ComboBox)
        {
            (control as ComboBox).Text = String.Empty;
        }
        else if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control) > 0)
        {
            ClearControls(control);
        }
    }
}
```

My suggestion would be to **take advantage of the MVVM pattern** instead. In this case you will have the control contents bound to properties in a view model class. To clear all controls in this case, you will only have to replace `DataContext` with a new instance of the view model class. Check HighCore's answer for details.

Comment: @Pallavi It is important to mention that this approach has **ALL SORTS OF PROBLEMS** due to `UI Virtualization` and the WPF Content Model and the way a TabControl creates and destroys UI elements dynamically and Visual versus Logical Trees. DO NOT use this approach. WPF is NOT winforms, see my answer.

Comment: what is root here. tabitem

Comment: @Pallavi I'd also like to reiterate what @HighCore has said. This approach is going to work only in very simple scenarios where the visual tree doesn't change during runtime (i.e. no conrtols derived from `ItemsControl`). If you are going to use this, do it only as an **interim solution** and consider changing your approach to proper MVVM model ASAP.

Comment: @Pallavi `root` should be your window or any other top level container control, containing all the child controls you want to "clear".

Answer (score 4):

> I am famliar with windows forms, Now i am going to start WPF

Excellent. Welcome to the light side.

The first thing you need to do is to completely forget everything you've learned in winforms and understand and embrace [**The WPF Mentality**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085).

> in winforms i reset the controls with the following recursive method

in WPF, you don't "reset controls", you don't actually do much with controls, simply because [**UI is Not Data**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085).

What you do instead, is to declaratively [**DataBind**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) your UI to a relevant **Data Model** or **ViewModel**, and manipulate that instead.

Therefore, say define some data like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}

    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

and then you define (**IN XAML**) a piece of UI to show that data:

```
  <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
   </StackPanel>
```

What you do in order to "clear" these TextBoxes is to assign their [`DataContext`](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) to a new, clear instance of your data class:

`DataContext = new Person();`

I suggest you start reading the WPF Mentality link.

Good luck.

Comment: +1 excellent write up. I am sure @HighCore didn't want to clutter the answer, because there is a lot to cover in WPF, but for bindings to respond, don't forget for the class, in this sample `Person`, to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the PropertyChanged event on properties that are being used in XAML Bindings.

Comment: @Denismorozov that's right. There's much more to WPF than this, but all the links I posted should get the OP started.