# WPF add StackPanel child control from DataContext by XAML

Tags: wpf, datacontext, stackpanel

I want WPF read C# Object's properties. And convert these properties name to  WPF's Label controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StackPanel` does NOT generate items. It's only a `Panel`, whose function is `Layout` only.

You're looking for an [`ItemsControl`](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <!-- ... -->
</ItemsControl>
```

which, by default will have a `StackPanel` as it's [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Notice also that setting the `DataContext` to a single *instance* of a class will NOT make the `ItemsControl` create any elements. You need to set the `ItemsSource` property to an [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (for example a `List<MyClass>` or the like).

```
//Window Constructor
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = New List<MyClass>
                  {
                      //.. Items here
                  };
}
```

And no, WPF does not automatically read `Attribute`s from properties. You can create a ViewModel which does that, or hard-code the display names in XAML.

Comment: +1 Nice to see you answering questions again after your commenting period. :)

Comment: @sheridan I keep waiting for [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21004225/643085) *"Ok, Delete all your code and start all over..."* kind of situations... :P

Comment: You shouldn't have to wait long... every other mother here claims to be using WPF and MVVM and half of them aren't using either!!