# How to create Image Grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, modern-ui

I would like to ask, how can I easily create a grid or view with images in WPF C#. I am interested in simple view, where all images are sized uniformly with fixed spacing between them - like basic gallery.

Images would be loaded dynamically, number of them varyies for each item.

Is anything like that available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: No, I was searching through the Internet, but I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: Consider using an ItemsControl with a UniformGrid as ItemsPanel and an ItemTemplate with an Image control.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I don't see anything you wrote in WPF Controls.

Comment: How many rows/columns are you looking for? or do you want it to change based on number of pictures?

Comment: I would like to change that automatically based on amount of images.

Comment: @Supermartzin I mean exactly what I wrote. ItemsControl, UniformGrid and Image are all WPF controls. Look these things up in MSDN or get a WPF book. You need to show a minimum of own effort in order to get help here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it and try to figure something out.

Comment: @Supermartzin I closed this question as a duplicate. See [My Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21004225/643085) with detailed instructions on how to create an "Image Gallery" like UI in WPF using adequate WPF concepts such as ItemsControls, DataBinding and DataTemplates.