# Add Dynamic (Image + textblock) in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am currently doing an application on Windows Phone 8 to create formations game, the user creates a demand each player, this is done dynamically. The problem is that when I do dynamic as follows:

```
  private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Grid grilla = new Grid();           

     Image img = new Image();
     Random rnd = new Random();
     int leftPos =  rnd.Next(0, 300);
     int rightPos = rnd.Next(0, 300);
     string ruta = "Images/Icons/1387004933_school_events.png";
     BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@ruta, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
     img.Height = 45;
     img.Width = 45;
     img.Source = bm;            
     img.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(MouseMoving);
     img.Margin = new Thickness(leftPos, rightPos, rightPos, leftPos);
     MouseDragElementBehavior mouseDragElementBehavior = new MouseDragElementBehavior();
     mouseDragElementBehavior.ConstrainToParentBounds = true;
     //Interaction.GetBehaviors(img).Add(mouseDragElementBehavior);
     grilla.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(MouseMoving);
     Interaction.GetBehaviors(grilla).Add(mouseDragElementBehavior);

     TextBlock caja = new TextBlock();
     caja.Text = "Name Player";

     grilla.Children.Add(caja);
     grilla.Children.Add(img);
     grilla.Width = 300;
     grilla.Height = 300;

     ContentPanel.Children.Add(grilla);
 }
```

It's dynamically created and added Handler to be Drag & Drop but when added want both image (45x45) as texblock appear together or with self-adjusting, as along as possible and under each other, Actually, the image is very biggest. Help me!

|image|

|Name Player|

In this order

Comment: delete all that and use an `ItemsControl` in XAML.

Comment: Thanks @HighCore any example please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21004225/643085