# ListBox with customized Item in VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, listbox

[image]

I want to modify the original ListBox control that the each item to have a CheckBox, Labels and a Button control inside.

Is there any optimal method to make that? without making Custom Control from the very beginning?

Making custom control that inherits ListBox could be not a bad idea, but don't know how...

### Thank you!

I tried WPF but it was too difficult at this time. Actually, designing the control via XAML was easy, but managing the list items(add/delete with texts, get event from the button in each item) wasn't.

Comment: You can make a `UserControl` and add those to a `FlowLayoutPanel` instead of a `Listbox`.

Comment: `managing the list items(add/delete with texts, get event from the button in each item) wasn't.` - No you don't do any of that in WPF. you create a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding to populate the UI from the Data in the ViewModel instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is tagged `[WPF]` I'm going to provide a WPF answer:

The first thing any developer who faces WPF immediately tries to do is to use it as if it were winforms. This is a big mistake.

If you're working with WPF, you really need to leave behind the traditional aproach used in archaic technologies such as winforms, and understand and embrace [**The WPF Mentality**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/643085).

in WPF, you don't "add/delete with texts, get event from the button in each item" or any of that, simply because [**UI is not Data**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085).

Instead, you define a simple Data Model:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string MyText1 {get;set;}

    public string MyText2 {get;set;}
}
```

and then **declaratively** define [**Data Bindings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) in the UI to *"show"* this data to the UI as opposed to *"reading" or "writing"* data to/from the UI:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication14"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="5" Background="LightCyan" BorderBrush="LightSkyBlue" BorderThickness="2">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Text 1:" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Text 2:" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyText1}"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyText2}"/>

                        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

And finally, you define the [**DataContext**](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) of the Window or View to a relevant instance or collection of such data:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = Enumerable.Range(0,10)
                                .Select(x => new MyData()
                                {
                                    MyText1 = "Text1 - " + x.ToString(),
                                    MyText2 = "Text2 - " + x.ToString()
                                });
    }
}
```

All this results in:

[image]

See? really simple and beautiful.

Forget winforms, **WPF Rocks**. Just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, short of using WPF, is to create a custom `UserControl` which represents each item that will go in the list.  Then, add a `FlowLayoutPanel` to your form.  Set the panel's `AutoScroll` property to `True`.  Then set its `FlowDirection` property to `TopToBottom`.  Then, dynamically create one of your custom controls for each item that you need to add to the list and call the panel's `Controls.Add` method to add them to the list.