# WPF make controls in dockpanel with same height same time filling all dock space?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

My problem is very simple ,

I have a dock panel which i fill with buttons programmatically  using this code

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< 5 ; i++)
{

Button btn = new Button();
btn.Content = "test";
btn.Height = Double.NaN;                  
DockPanel.SetDock(btn, Dock.Top);
dock1.Children.Add(btn);

}
```

Filling this dock

```
<DockPanel x:Name="dock1" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightSkyBlue"    >
```

If I set LastChildFill to `False`

this is the result :- 
[image]

If I set LastChildFill to `True`

this is the result :-
[image]

**What I want is these buttons to fill the dockpanel with same height and fill the area of the panel fully**

Like this :-

[image]

Comment: You want a `<Grid>`.

Comment: use XAML to define your UI, not procedural code to create it. And a `DockPanel` is not an appropriate container for this. Use a `StackPanel` and add `Margin`s to your Buttons.

Comment: The buttons creation is based on DB query , so it can't be  predefined . @HighCore

Comment: @xsari3x I never said it should be "predefined". You need to learn to use WPF properly. Start reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21315083/643085) and follow the links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may perhaps use `UniformGrid` with 1 Column, this will hep you to distribute the space and size uniformly

example code

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1" Margin="10,0">
    <Button Height="25" Content="Motor gas 1:35 %"/>
    <Button Height="25" Content="Motor gas 2:36 %"/>
    <Button Height="25" Content="Motor gas 3:36 %"/>
    <Button Height="25" Content="Motor Air:200 %"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

result

[image: result]

here is code behind approach for the above example

xaml

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1" Margin="10,0" x:Name="uGrid1" Grid.Column="1" />
```

code

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< 5 ; i++)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Content = "test";
    btn.Height = 25;
    uGrid1.Children.Add(btn);
}
```