# Win Forms GUI design: Showing extremely large number of GUI components without reaching USER Object limit?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I have this problem: In my app, I need to show custom user control, for each element of the list that is provided from database at runtime. Each user control, when created, contains around 30 User objects (buttons, grid, labels, combo boxes etc), so, when the list contains over 300 elements, the limit of allowed USER Objects is reached.

There are no memory leaks, Handles are fine, GDI Objects are also fine. All the controls are added to a TableLayout.

Has anyone had a similar problem, and how did you fix it? 
Is there any other way except paging or drawing each control dynamically by controlling if it should be visible on screen, based on the scroll position of the table layout?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: winforms doesn't support large GUIs. You're looking for WPF.

Comment: @HighCore even though, an application shouldn't have to contain this much elements. I think there's some design issue, but you can prove me wrong with a screenshot of the app.

Comment: @Kilazur it's not a matter of "design" or that an application shouldn't have many controls. It's a matter of winforms being a completely useless platform that doesn't support anything. The OP stated that he's doing a scrollable list-like UI where each item is a user control. Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22922233/643085) which I ended up providing a [WPF Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23023207/643085) for because the only way to resolve winforms' incapabilities is to forget winforms and use technology from this century.

Comment: Thank you HighCore... that's also what I thought, but, unfortunately, at this stage of the project it is not possible to change technology :(

Comment: @Alex you can also implement this specific part of the application in WPF, while leaving the existing winforms stuff intact. You can integrate WPF content in an existing winforms application using the [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx)