# .net Docked Panel with autoscroll enabled does not show all controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autoscroll

I have distilled this problem down to the least amount of lines of code (below).  I have a panel, docked inside a groupbox.  The panel.autoscroll = true. After the code executes, it only show less than the 2000 checkboxes loaded onto the panel.  In other words, after the code executes, you scroll to the bottom of the Panel and the last checkbox is # 16xx.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Rich

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        int iMax = 2000;
        int iTopPosition = 0;

        GroupBox aGroupbox = new GroupBox();
        Point aPointGB = new Point(10, 10);
        aGroupbox.Location = aPointGB;
        aGroupbox.Height = 200;
        aGroupbox.Width = 200;
        aGroupbox.Text = "A Container for a scrollable Panel";

        Panel aPanel = new Panel();
        aPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        aPanel.AutoScroll = true;
        aGroupbox.Controls.Add(aPanel);

        this.Controls.Add(aGroupbox);

        for (i = 0; i < iMax; i++)
        {
            CheckBox aCheckBox = new CheckBox();
            aCheckBox.Name = "chk_" + i.ToString();
            aCheckBox.Text = i.ToString();
            Point aPoint = new Point(0, iTopPosition);
            aCheckBox.Location = aPoint;
            iTopPosition += 20;
            aPanel.Controls.Add(aCheckBox);
        }
    }
```

Comment: **2000** checkboxes? Seriously? Anyway no, controls position is limited by windows API (details in other posts here on SO) so you can't have a control with such big offset.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [My Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23023207/643085) to a [Similar Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22922233/643085) which involves leaving behind obsolete archaic winforms and replacing it by modern technology which is actually capable of handling data.

Comment: BTW, @AdrianoRepetti 2000 checkboxes doesn't sound crazy if there is a multiple-selection ListBox containing 2000 items from which the user can choose. To improve usability I would also place a filter TextBox on top of the list to provide a way to quickly find elements. Surely a winforms mentality doesn't even fathom such a thing, but in modern technologies it's perfectly feasible.

Comment: Adriano, yes I understand this design is poor, but, its a legacy issue and I have to tweak it, or throw it out and redesign the entire thing. I appreciate your comments. After reading HighCores comments, I realized one solution might be to use a CheckedListBox to contain all the checkboxes...

Comment: @HighCore yes IMO they're really too many. Unfiltered list is impractical (at best) so it should never be visible to users (even if easy to filter). You filter and you select few, change filter select others and no way to see what you selected unless you repeat filtering again (or you scroll an endless list). I hope I'll never have to use something like that. IMO they should ALWAYS be categorized (even a raw tree-view is better than nothing) to present no more than 10/20 items per page. Well but UI design isn't a topic for SO...

Comment: @rynaskir Yes, I understand you can't simply change it. I was just astonished! Anyway HighCore solution (CheckedListBox) is pretty nice to solve this issue!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti which can be achieved as easy as 1,2,3 in decent, usable technologies as opposed to archaic winforms... which was my initial point.

Comment: @HighCore I absolutely agree about that (drop WinForms), I understood you thought 2000 checkboxes are kind of _usable_ idea!