# Which control to display text to be programmatically edited later on

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently developing a chat application in C# and I would like to know which form control allows to add text retaining control to each specific message to modify it later on when is required. I want this in order to be able to add a double tick when the message is received in the other side of the communication, pretty much like in "Whatsapp".

I've thought about an approach consisting on each message object firing events (like "sent", "received"..) when it changes that are listened by the corresponding form control that serves as the view, adding the above mentioned tick.

Any advice on how to achieve this goal? I've tried TextBox but Lines property force to have control os indexes and I want it to be completely event driven. Currently I stuck with DataGridView, however I've made little to no progress.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try the RichTextBox control. For this scenario the AppendText method could be useful..

Comment: No, he want easy access to the chunks.

Comment: @TaW you're right, that fact slipped by me.. maybe a custom control derived from the RichTextBox could do the trick..

Comment: @Kaplan: Have you thought about the numbers of chat items you need to a) display b) keep ready for searching,storing etc..? Without such an estimate the best way to go can't really be decided on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one ready made Control I can think of will do the job, I'm afraid.

I would use a `FlowLayoutPanel` and add a `Label` for each chunk of text that gets added to the chat.

You can use `MeasureString` with a given width to get the height of the `Label`. (`AutoSize` should be off.)

The Labels would get the Width of the FLP and you could keep a `List<>` of the Labels with maybe a few meta data, like user, time etc..

Sounds like a good candidate for a ChatDisplay class to bundle the whole functionality!

Of course as the Labels are Controls you can add events to them as you like to communicate with the ChatDisplay or even with an outside communications object.. And the ChatDisplay class is free to implement whatever you need anyway. If necessary you can wrap the Labels in a ChatItem class, too.

Much more extensible than digging into a DGV to force it into doing things it was not meant to do..

Comment: It's important to let the OP know that your proposed solution has a [huge performance drawback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22922233/643085) and it will become pretty much unusable as the amount of data increases, and that the OP should seriously consider [using proper UI technology](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23023207/643085) which can handle this scenario perfectly well, as opposed to insist on trying to get anything decent of out winforms.

Comment: Well if display performance in a chat were a problem, then you would be right. But it is not and you, as usual, talk about things which you, as you have told me, do not actaully know..

Comment: sorry, I do not need to investigate by myself to find out winforms is useless and retarded. See the linked question where the OP clearly stated then ran into performance problems when adding lots of UI elements into a `FlowLayoutPanel` trying get a complex List-like UI in winforms. The same exact thing is going to happen to the OP here when trying to create the chat application with rich text features or media. winforms is a worthless piece of crap, whether you admit it or not. My advice to use proper technology is much better than letting people stick to dinosaur crap.

Comment: This is utter nonsense.

Comment: prove it. Create your proposed `FlowLayoutPanel` solution and add 100,000 rich text entries. Then I'll do the same using modern technology and we can compare whose approach works better and requires less code ;)

Comment: Go away! You are molesting me! The very __idea__ of a chat with 100.000 entries on the client application is coming from a si*k mind. We can keep those data in Lists __equally__ well and can display a __reasonable__ amount equally well, too, obviously. Anything else are just imagined problems. I told you before to leave me alone, at least until next year.. (Reading M.MacDonald WPF Pro atm; I like that, but it'll be XMas by the end of it.) Writing a reasonably well working Chat is no problem in Winforms, believe me.

Comment: what you are describing above is called UI virtualization, a technique by which, given an in-memory List of Data Items and an Items-based UI, the UI only loads as many Data Items as to populate the currently visible region based on scrolling offsets. Then, as the end user scrolls down/up thru the list, additional data items are loaded and no-longer visible ones are unloaded. Modern technologies have this feature built-in, whereas in winforms you have to implement it yourself, leading to a larger, winforms-specific codebase. My point still stands that it's better to use modern technology.

Comment: @HighCore Can you explain your point further? I have chosen Winforms since I thought this could be better because I am using Windows XP to debug the app. Now port this to WPF would be maybe too work that won't worth the effort as far as I won't expect this app to be of much importance. However it would be useful in the future.

Comment: @TaW Why is necessary to use `MeasureString` function?

Comment: Using Labels to display the separate chat chunks you will want to give each a fixed width, a little less than the FLP's width; but the Height need to be calculated: `using (Graphics G = label.CreateGraphics())        label.Height = (int)(G.MeasureString(txt, label.Font, label.Width).Height) + 6;`, the 6pixels being a little padding. Note that the width is passed in and the resulting Size will have the necessary Height to hold the text..

Comment: @Kaplan `"Can you explain your point further?"` - See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22922233/643085) where the OP implemented a FlowLayoutPanel-based solution as proposed in this answer, resulting in an enormous performance penalty as the amount of data increased, due to winforms' lack of proper UI virtualization features to deal with big data sets. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23023207/643085) where I provide a WPF based solution that is capable of dealing with whatever amounts of data due to UI virtualization, not losing performance whatsoever.

Comment: @Kaplan all in all, whatever you can do in winforms can be done in WPF with 10% the amount of code and effort due to advanced WPF features such as DataBinding, UI virtualization, Data Templating and so on. winforms is not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications.

Comment: @HighCore Although I've eventually choosen the other solution I'll keep your advice for a future occassion.

Comment: Here is advice which (I hope) HighCore will agree with me: It'll be best if you try to write the code in a way that separates the data logic classes, like a ChatItem and a ChatController from the classes that will actually do the display, like a ChatPanel; this way you can re-use the data logic or rewrite the display logic without the two interferring with each other. I bet we could come up with a set of data classes that can equally well be wired up with a Winforms app or a WPF app..