# C# add avatar to RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf, richtext

What I'm trying to accomplish here , is having the ability to add a text msg like this:

[image]

to be able to make a chat box , where I have lets say 1000 msgs , like this .. So I created a custom `RichTextBox` as follow :

```
public class CustomRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
        public CustomRichTextBox()
        {

        }
        public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
        {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
        {
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in ba)
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            return hex.ToString();
        }

        public void AddPic(Image img)
        {
            string imgStr = ByteArrayToString(ImageToByte(img));
            string mpic = @"{\pict\pngblip\picw" +
                          img.Width.ToString() + @"\pich" + img.Height.ToString() +
                          @"\picwgoal" + img.Width.ToString() + @"\pichgoal" + img.Height.ToString() +
                          @"\hex " + imgStr + "}";

            Rtf +=  mpic + " Username \r\n Said!...";
        }
    }
```

but nothing really shows on the `RichTextBox` , what I'm missing here!? I just want it to show the avatar and a paragraph next to it , later I will change the `font/color etc`

Comment: Use a UserControl with a RTB and some other control that can display an image like picturebox, label, panel etc.. - Note that RTB has neither Padding nor a Paint event so an attempt to subclass it will not work well.

Comment: @TaW wouldn't that be too much controls , to make a basic chat msg?

Comment: No. Actually, if you care about efficiency you shouldn't even use a RTB! Instead draw all the stuff onto a Panel! This is the cheapest and most flexible design.. use one textbox for text entry and draw all previous messages!

Comment: Or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446450/which-control-to-display-text-to-be-programmatically-edited-later-on/25448562#25448562)

Comment: @Taw I think appending/editing text is more better/efficient than , redrawing the whole `panel` to show 1000 msgs!

Comment: @TaW I saw your last reply , I was trying to avoid that at all cost , was hoping if there was better solution!

Comment: On what screen do you expect to show 1000 messages? If you want the avatar to preceed each message btw, you can insert them via Clipboard into the RTB. Very fragile though to user editing. RTB is no more efficient to draw all those colored pixels than GDI+..

Comment: @TaW thank you a lot  , you can add this as an answer , and if there is no one came up with a better solution , I will consider your answer as the right one!

Answer (score 0):

I think your avatar image as well as textbox for username should be separate controls from comment/message contents. This is sort of how it should be done:

```
<StackPanel orientation="horizontal">
    <Image alt="avatar" />
    <StackPanel orientation="vertical">
        <TextBox>Username</TextBox>
        <RichTextBox>Message or Comment</RichTextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Translate to your layout of choice.

Comment: This is a Winforms question!

Comment: @TaW and? I gave an example. I am not saying it's winforms markup. I am just trying to give an OP an idea of how it should look.