# Controls overlapping in a panel after a threshold number of controls added to it

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, controls, panel

I have written a store procedure which returns a group of tables and their names.
I am rendering them into a Panel. For the table name I have a label which holds the value "Table Name : " and a TextBox control which actually holds the table name. Followed to that, there's a DataGridView which holds the table data. You can see how it is displayed below:

[image: How the information is displayed]

Now what happens is for very large returned result, after the data is rendered in form of controls, some of the controls gets overlapped in the bottom of the Panel. You can see that in the below image:

[image: The Overlapping of controls]
Basically the DataGridView, Label and TextBox controls are getting overlapped. I don't know what's the cause of this problem.

**Almost 576 tables i.e. 49980 rows are getting returned as data to be rendered.**

Here's the code which I used to render the controls in the Panel.

```
int Offset = 0, RowCount = 0;
GridPanel.Controls.Clear();
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    RowCount += table.Rows.Count;
    if (table.Rows.Count == 1 && table.Columns.Count == 1 && table.Columns[0].ColumnName.Equals("Table Name"))
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = "Table Name : ";
        label.Width = 100;
        label.Location = new Point(5, Offset + 12);

    TextBox tableName = new TextBox();
    tableName.Text = table.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
    tableName.Width = table.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString().Length < 200 ? 200
        : Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString().Length * 0.8);
    tableName.ReadOnly = true;
    tableName.BackColor = Color.White;
    tableName.GotFocus += tableName_GotFocus;
    tableName.Location = new Point(label.Width + 10, Offset + 10);

    label.Font = tableName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold,
        System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

    GridPanel.Controls.Add(label);
    GridPanel.Controls.Add(tableName);

    Offset += (10 + tableName.Height + 10);
}
else
{
    DataGridView TableGrid = new DataGridView();
    TableGrid.Width = GridPanel.Width - 20;
    TableGrid.Height = ((table.Rows.Count * 40) < 62 ? 62
        : (table.Rows.Count * 40 + 50 > 300 ? 300
        : (table.Rows.Count * 40 + 50)));
    TableGrid.MinimumSize = new Size(GridPanel.Width - 20, 62);
    TableGrid.MaximumSize = new Size(GridPanel.Width - 20, 300);
    TableGrid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
    TableGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    TableGrid.Location = new Point(0, Offset);
    TableGrid.DataSource = table;

    GridPanel.Controls.Add(TableGrid);

    Offset += TableGrid.Height;
}
}
MessageBox.Show(RowCount.ToString());
```

Can anyone please give me an idea of what is basically happening here. Is it the maximum limit of controls that can be rendered in a Panel or is it any mistake in my code?

Comment: [Simple, beautiful, extensible, maintainable example of how to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23023207/643085). No Weird size calculations, no manual .Location stuff or anything like that. Just simple properties and DataBinding.

Comment: But the given example is in WPF, right? How can I imitate the same in winform...??

Comment: you can't. that's the whole point. winforms is completely useless and deprecated. Use current technology instead of trying to get anything decent out of winforms.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the suggestion @HighCore. Anyways I need to implement the same in winforms itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use flowLayoutPanel in place of panel.

Comment: No its not working. It just adds some space beneath and you  can scroll down  more to an empty space...!!