# How to display Object data in a TableLayoutPanel in a performant way

Tags: winforms, performance, c#-4.0, optimization, tablelayoutpanel

I have written the folowing code to populate the data from a object in a tablelayoutpanel control. It works Smile | :) , but when its loading the data onto the table, it flickers/jumps for few seconds and then after 2-3 seconds when its done processing the data it populates the data Frown | :( . I believe this behaviour is because of the code written for dynamically processing & drawing of the various controls in the table based on the object data.

I need your help in optimising the code/improving the performance of this code so that the table can load smoothly and fast. Please help. Thanks.

PS: This code is written for a table containing small amount of data. But going forward the same is planned for populating table with 4X more data. If this is the case, then performance will be very poor, which worries me. Please suggest some ideas.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Common obj = new Common();
        obj.CreateDeserializedXmlObject(@"E:\TestReport.xml");
        var v = obj.GetAdminData();

        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 4;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = ((v.DOCREVISIONS.Length * 4) + 1 + (v.USEDLANGUAGES.L10.Length));


        Label labelLanguage = new Label();
        Label labelUsedLanguage = new Label();
        Label labelDocRevisions = new Label();

        labelLanguage.Text = "Language:";
        labelUsedLanguage.Text = "Used Language:";
        labelDocRevisions.Text = "Doc-Revisions:";

        ComboBox comboBoxLanguage = new ComboBox();
        comboBoxLanguage.Items.Add(v.LANGUAGE.Value.ToString());
        comboBoxLanguage.SelectedIndex = 0;

        ComboBox comboBoxUsedLanguage = new ComboBox();
        foreach (LPLAINTEXT Lang in v.USEDLANGUAGES.L10)
        {
            comboBoxUsedLanguage.Items.Add(Lang.L.ToString());
        }
        comboBoxUsedLanguage.SelectedIndex = 0;
        int index = 0;

        Label[] labelDocRevision = new Label[v.DOCREVISIONS.Length];
        Label[] labelRevision = new Label[v.DOCREVISIONS.Length];
        Label[] labelState = new Label[v.DOCREVISIONS.Length];
        Label[] labelTeamMember = new Label[v.DOCREVISIONS.Length];
        Label[] labelDate = new Label[v.DOCREVISIONS.Length];

        TextBox[] textBoxRevision = new TextBox[v.DOCREVISIONS.Length];
        TextBox[] textBoxState = new TextBox[v.DOCREVISIONS.Length];
        TextBox[] textBoxTeamMember = new TextBox[v.DOCREVISIONS.Length]; 
        TextBox[] textBoxDate = new TextBox[v.DOCREVISIONS.Length];

        foreach (DOCREVISION dcr in v.DOCREVISIONS)
        {
            labelDocRevision[index] = new Label();
            labelRevision[index] = new Label();
            labelState[index] = new Label();
            labelTeamMember[index] = new Label();
            labelDate[index] = new Label();

            textBoxRevision[index] = new TextBox();
            textBoxState[index] = new TextBox();
            textBoxTeamMember[index] = new TextBox();
            textBoxDate[index] = new TextBox();

            labelDocRevision[index].Text = "DOCREVISION["+index.ToString()+"]:";
            labelRevision[index].Text = "Revision:";
            labelState[index].Text = "State:";
            labelTeamMember[index].Text = "TeamMemberRef:";
            labelDate[index].Text = "Date:";

            textBoxRevision[index].Text = dcr.REVISIONLABEL.Value.ToString();
            textBoxState[index].Text = dcr.STATE.Value.ToString();
            textBoxTeamMember[index].Text = dcr.TEAMMEMBERREF.Value.ToString();
            textBoxDate[index].Text = dcr.DATE.Value.ToString();

            index++;
        }


        // Add child controls to TableLayoutPanel and specify rows and column
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelLanguage, 0, 0);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelUsedLanguage, 0, 1);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelDocRevisions, 0, 2);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(comboBoxLanguage, 1, 0);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(comboBoxUsedLanguage, 1, 1);

        int docRevRowSpacing = 2;
        for (int loop = 0; loop < index; loop++)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelDocRevision[loop], 1, docRevRowSpacing);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelRevision[loop], 2, docRevRowSpacing);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelState[loop], 2, docRevRowSpacing+1);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelTeamMember[loop], 2, docRevRowSpacing+2);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelDate[loop], 2, docRevRowSpacing+3);

            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(textBoxRevision[loop], 3, docRevRowSpacing);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(textBoxState[loop], 3, docRevRowSpacing+1);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(textBoxTeamMember[loop],3 , docRevRowSpacing+2);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(textBoxDate[loop], 3, docRevRowSpacing+3);

            docRevRowSpacing += 4;
        }

        tableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
        Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
    }
```

Comment: While doing some trials, i found that - changing the CellBorderStyle from Single to None, speeds up. Alternatively, i tried hiding the tablelayout before processing the data and showing it after everything is done, this also helps.

DataGridView Control was my initial choice, but i faced lot of challenges in binding the object (source) with the Datagrid, also it was difficult adding different controls in required layout, in the datagrid. So i switched to TableLayout.

If anyone can suggest some optimisation for my code, then that will be helpful.
Thank u :)

Comment: [**Solution: use WPF.**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23023207/643085) winforms is useless and doesn't support anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are two minor changes that helps a little bit.

At the start of your code you can call [`SuspendLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx). This prevents the TableLayoutPanel to redraw itself every time you add a control to it. When you're done adding all controls at the end you call [`ResumeLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout(v=vs.110).aspx). At that moment the TableLayoutPanel will redraw only once. It still takes time but at least most the flickering is gone. At the end of your example code you add the `tableLayoutPanel1` again to the forms control collection. If the TableLayoutPanel is on your form designer you don't need that and by doing it you make your performance worse because now you have two tableLayoutPanels that need to be painted.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
     // all your other code goes here

     // not sure why you add the tableLayouyPanel AGAIN to the
     // form control collection. 
     // Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
     tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
}
```

I noticed in my testing that resizing the form gives the same flickering effect. I used the [ResizeBegin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizebegin(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ResizeEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend(v=vs.110).aspx) events to do the same Suspend and Resume layout trick:

```
private void Form1_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
}

private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
}
```

This as much as you can do with your current code (except maybe the use of all those arrays with controls but their overhead is not the major issue here).

The [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) is maybe not the best control for what you want to achieve. It lacks for example [VirtualMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx) support, something the [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) does. That would enable you to only load and show data that is visible on the form (and therefor create controls for it). Adapting your code to use that control is left as an exercise for the reader and if new issues pop-up feel free to start a new question.