# WPF C# How can I add this argument

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF C# application. I was wondering how I can make this call on an Click button. Here is the code:

```
    void tabControl_TabItemAdded(object sender, TabItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();
        DynamicGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        e.TabItem.Content = DynamicGrid;
```

The TabItemEventArgs e is the call I want to make on this button. Here is the code:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.TabItem.Content = SOMETHING HERE
```

How can I move my item?

Comment: delete all that and use proper XAML and DataBinding for whatever you're trying to do

Comment: No there is probably more to the .CS sheet that can be done.

Comment: `.CS sheet` - Sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about. Delete all that and use proper XAML and DataBinding.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Trying to modify XAML via code is extremely problematic. Consult [New UI Creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303985/).