# How i can get the value of cell in datagrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid, with a number of rows. I want to get the value of cell[0]. 
In the window form I was using this code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == null)
            {
                //do somthing
            }
         }
```

The problem is, I do not know how to get the value of the cell, as this code does not work in WPF.

Comment: Your code occurs an error when you compile it, try to correct your code before asking question :)

Comment: Remove the last " ) " and try this :
comboBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

Comment: @Mahmoud - I have removed the typos from your question. Make sure to post correct code otherwise you will get answers correcting that typos for you instead of actual answers you expecting from community.

Comment: "Which is it: `dataGridView` or `DataGrid`? `Winforms` or `WPF`?

Comment: @Mahmoud - What's the first cell look like? Can't you get the value from underlying data object binded with dataGrid?

Comment: @RohitVats I edited my question   and my code it's working in a window forms i want same in a wpf

Comment: @Mahmoud - You should read more about WPF. WPF doesn't work same like WinForms. WPF is more powerful than WinForms in terms of data abstraction it provides. WPF is more oriented towards playing with underlying data source instead of playing with UI controls. That's why no Row property exist for WPF dataGrid because you can get the values from underlying data object binded to dataGrid. Must read - [Transitioning from WinForms to WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/632337).

Comment: Edit your code like this :
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                //do somthing
            }

Comment: @RohitVats Ok i know WPF doesn't work same like WinForms ,i want code wpf work same like this code

Comment: @Mahmoud - I have added an answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, you need to read more on WPF and bindings that how it works because **value which you are trying to get from UI can easily be fetched from underlying data object**.

Say you have binded dataGrid to some list **`ObservableCollection<MyObject>`** and first column of dataGrid is binded to property **`Name`**. You can get value for first cell simply like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string value = ((MyObject)dataGridView1.Items[0]).Name;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBlock.Text))
    {
       // do something.
    }
}
```

---

That being said, assuming first cell is simple *DataGridTextColumn*, you can get the value in traditional WinForms way in WPF like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    TextBlock textBlock = dataGridView1.Columns[0]
                         .GetCellContent(dataGridView1.Items[i]) as TextBlock;
    if (textBlock != null)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBlock.Text))
        {
            // do something.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the my object ? ((MyObject)dataGridView1.Items[0]).Name;

Comment: `MyObject` will be name of your class. I suspect `MyGrid` in your case if i remember correctly from your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is a comparison operator. `=` is used for assignment:

```
comboBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: This won't compile. DataGrid doesn't have any Rows property. Most likely it was just a typo.

Comment: @Raging Bull code does not work with datagrid in WPF

Comment: @aEkBKF This code it's working in a window form , i want to code work like this work in a wpf