# Programmatically moving TextBlocks in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been reading some tutorials on XAML but it does not help me. I have an empty application window and I need to create 30 TextBoxes in 3 rows.

Being used on the win forms, I thought I would figure it out - well, I did not. I cannot seem to find a way how to create them on certain coordinates.

Comment: what you  have tried  ??

Comment: Why do you need them to be at specific coordinates? WPF has much better `Panel`s than the `Canvas`. Most people take advantage of a `Grid`, `StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, `FlowPanel`, etc.

Comment: So I cannot simply do things like ..X=Previous_X+50?

Comment: Yes you can but then you might as well simply use winforms!? WPF is designed to be much more flexible.

Comment: do you  need to create them from code behind at runtime  or in XAML

Answer (score 3):

You first want to place a `Canvas` control on your screen, then you can populate it with TextBoxes placed at whatever `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` position you want.

That said though, WPF has a much better layout/arrangement system than WinForms, and trying to use it like it's WinForms means you'll miss out on a lot of what makes WPF so great, and you'll be making things a lot harder on yourself.

The WPF way of doing the same thing would be to use an [ItemsControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/), and a collection of objects that each contain data that the UI needs to to know for display purposes.

First you would create a class to represent each TextBox

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

*Note: This class should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to change the properties at runtime and have the UI automatically update.*

Then make a list of this class, and bind it to an `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfMyClass}" />
```

Then you'd want to overwrite the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to be a `Canvas` (the best WPF panel for positioning items according to an X,Y position)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfMyClass}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Next overwrite the `ItemTemplate` to draw each item using a TextBlock

```
<!-- ItemTemplate -->
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

And add an `ItemContainerStyle` that binds Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties to X,Y properties on your object

```
<!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And this will take a List of `MyClass` objects, and render them to the screen inside a Canvas, with each item positioned at the specified X,Y coordinates.

With all that being said, are you sure this is what you want? WPF has much better layout panels than WinForms, and you don't have to position every element according to an X,Y coordinate if you don't want to.

For a quick visual introduction of WPF's Layouts, I'd recommend this link : [WPF Layouts - A Visual Quick Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start)

Also since it sounds like you're new to WPF and coming from a WinForms background, you may find this answer to a related question useful : [Transitioning from Windows Forms to WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/302677)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I used a Canvas because OP specified they want to set items at a specific X,Y coordinate, and the `Canvas` is the best control to do that with. I agree that for the grid-like layout being described, a different panel would most likely be best. Also, I changed the TextBlock to a Textbox, thanks :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Please don't ever use Margin for positioning in WPF lol :) The whole point of WPF's layouts is to make a consistent screen regardless of screen size or resolution, and positioning controls using Margin just defeats the point of that. The `Margin` property should be used to add a specific amount of whitespace around a control, and not for positioning a control

Comment: @PatrickHofman Nope, but `Canvas.Left` is meant for positioning items at a specific X coordinate, unlike `Margin`. It's easy for other WPF developers to read, understand, and maintain your code. Also, I think it may matter for things like how a parent panel deals with a child that is positioned out of bounds, depending on what type of panel it is :)

Answer (score 1):

WPF layout involves choosing a layout container and placing your controls in it.  There are several different containers:

- The `Grid` container is a powerful tool for laying out your form in rows and columns.  You have complete control over the size of each cell, and you can have rows or columns "span" each other.
- The `DockPanel` container allows you to "dock" controls to the edges of your window or the center.  You'd use it to layout a window with smart icon bars, ribbons, status windows, and toolboxes, like Visual Studio itself.
- The `StackPanel` container can be used to stack controls either on top of each other or next to each other
- The `UniformGrid` container is a less powerful version of the  container that keeps all cells the same size.
- The `Canvas` container allows you to specify the X & Y coordinates of your controls.

There are one or two others but these are the ones I've used.

The bad thing about laying out a form using X & Y coordinates is that the form does not handle resizing well.  This can be exacerbated when you support globalization, as the labels and such for a string may be a lot longer in a foreign language.  The best example off the top of my head is Spanish.  A lot of English phrases, when translated to Spanish, are a lot longer.

The `Grid` container gives you the most control over layout.  Columns can automatically size themselves to the longest string in the column, while the rest of the columns adjust themselves as necessary, again automatically.  You don't have to write one line of code to get that effect; it's all there in the `Grid` control out of the box.

If you insist on laying out your form the Winforms way, use a `Canvas`.  But you're not going to get the benefit of using the more advanced layout facilities in the other containers, especially the `Grid` control.  I use that almost exclusively in my forms.

**EDIT**

Using layout controls other than `Canvas` means that you think about layout differently in WPF than in WinForms.  You work at a higher conceptual level and leave the details about figuring out where on the screen a particular control will be displayed to WPF.  You also don't have things like the WinForms `Anchor` property in WPF, which always seemed kind of a hack to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position the TextBoxes in a grid-way, use `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        ...
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
    ...

    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: You are better off using stack panels imo. Much easier to maintain.

Comment: Not if you set the column `Width` to `Auto`.

Answer (score 0):

The WPF  was designed to offer a power and rich framework for designer which make it a different from the classic winforms. You can achieve what want by adding  your TextBox control to a canvas and changing the attached property following is a full example illustrating  this:

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="mainCanvas" Margin="31,-10,-31,10">
            <TextBox Name="myTextBox" Canvas.Left="131" Canvas.Top="109" Height="84" Width="135"></TextBox>
            <Button Content="Button" Height="62" Canvas.Left="271" Canvas.Top="69" Width="91" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           myTextBox.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,(double)myTextBox.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)+50.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I  think that the OP whant an explicit way of doing position