# ListView with Checkboxes and Editable Fields?

Tags: winforms, listview, .net-4.0, checkbox

I have a ListView form that looks like this:

[image]

How do I make it so each cell is like an editable textbox so the user can edit the values by clicking on a cell? Like if they click on "Count" a text edit cursor should appear in-place and they should be able to type to change the value of the field (Not in a separate dialog box or text field)

Comment: [That's exactly what I'm talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532639/complex-ui-inside-listboxitem#). The response I got for that question is that if you need serious UI, you have to use a serious UI framework.

Comment: @HighCore Looks like I'd be better off using WPF then.

Comment: what about using a datagridview instead of a listview. Or use this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView

Comment: If you wanted to dig into it you could extend the list view. I did this once and it worked out really well. [I used some code that was found at the Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9188/Embedding-Controls-in-a-ListView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *ListView* is intended for flexible display of a list of items.  Similar to windows explorer's ability to show  icons, thumbnails, details and basic list, all from the same set of objects.  If you really want to edit all of the elements in your data objects, you should probably read up on *DataGridView* and data-binding.