# ListView OwnerDraw artifacting when using LargeIcon view

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, ownerdrawn

I have a ListView in a C# WinForms project with `OwnerDraw` set to true. I'm populating both LargeIcon and List views, as well as the `LargeImageList` and `SmallImageList` properties (both of which have only a single image as all items display the same icon).

List view is drawing without issue:

[image: ListView in View mode]

LargeIcon view displays correctly initially:

[image: ListView in LargeIcon mode, nothing selected]

but leaves background artifacts as the selected item changes (doesn't matter if clicking or using the arrow keys):

[image]

Also, as shown, there's an issue with the text being cut off if too long, but that's a secondary concern.

Here is my DrawItem event (`ORANGE` and `WHIE` are color constant values declared elsewhere):

```
private void ListView_DrawItem( object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e ) {
    ListView list = sender as ListView;

    if( e.Item.Selected ) {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle( new SolidBrush( ORANGE ), e.Bounds );
    } else {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle( new SolidBrush( WHITE ), new Rectangle( e.Bounds.Location, e.Bounds.Size ) );
    }

    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

    if( list.View == View.List ) {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage( list.SmallImageList.Images[0], new Point( e.Bounds.Left + 4, e.Bounds.Top ) );
        e.Graphics.DrawString( e.Item.Text, new Font( "SegoeUI", 10, FontStyle.Regular ), new SolidBrush( Color.Black ), new PointF( e.Bounds.Left + 22, e.Bounds.Top + 1 ) );
    } else if( list.View == View.LargeIcon ) {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage( list.LargeImageList.Images[0], new Point( e.Bounds.Left + ( ( e.Bounds.Width - 32 ) / 2 ), e.Bounds.Top ) );
        e.Graphics.DrawString( e.Item.Text, new Font( "SegoeUI", 10, FontStyle.Regular ), new SolidBrush( Color.Black ), new RectangleF( new PointF( e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top + 34 ), new SizeF( e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height - 34 ) ), new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center } );
    }
}
```

A lot of this has been trial and error, including the geometry calculations and using the `TextRenderingHint`, which I did to get font smoothing, but I'm not sure I'm using the right value.

I last did an owner-drawn ListView years ago, but I guess I'm rusty now, and for the life of me can't make it work. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532639/complex-ui-inside-listboxitem) might be interesting to you.

Comment: Your code can never reproduce the screenshot, the FillRectangle call uses the wrong brush when the item is not selected.  It should not use orange.  Which is certainly connected to the problem.  Looks like you edited the code and made the bug disappear.  Your text is clipped because the font size doesn't match text size for icon labels.

Comment: Yes, I pasted and edited the code to use the `ORANGE` because it's easier to read than the fully qualified constant value that resides in another class. Code fixed to also include a `WHITE` constant as it otherwise should. However, the bug has not "disappeared" and the problem remains. Thank you for catching the typo as well as the hint about the font size.