# Programming Languages for Windows

Tags: language-agnostic

I am compiling a list of programming languages for Windows. I am aware of Wikipedia the like, which has comprehensive lists of Languages available on Windows.

But what I am most interested in, are Programming Languages that can be used to create GUI Desktop apps for Windows, and those languages that are *not* listed in these places that list languages.

I know there are many, many more languages out there that aren't on the lists. But what are they?

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty bold statement. Why are others irrelevant?

Comment: research about WPF + XAML + MVVM and see [this video](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/) and compare the power of WPF and XAML to create datacentric solutions with whatever other frameworks out there.

Comment: the `only` other option I see is if you need to create powerful high FrameRate games where you would use C++ and Unity or XNA and DirectX directly. But for regular datacentric applications. WPF is the only relevant option for Windows.

Comment: @HighCore: those of us who make a living writing and maintaining Windows applications _without_ using WPF would probably disagree with your sweeping generalization. And there are many, many of us.

Comment: Any language with C FFI can be used. And there are many hundreds of such languages.

Comment: It would probably be easier to get a list of all programming languages and subtract the ones that cannot somehow be used for windows GUI programming.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman I don't really care dude. My point still stands. Show me something that is even remotely comparable with WPF and I'll change my mind. The fact that you don't use doesn't change the fact that it is technically superior to everything else.

Comment: @Igbylargeman seriously dude.. I thought you would come up with some hardcore UI framework we never heard of... but winforms? [you can't be serious](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15532639/643085).

Comment: <framework/language> is the best for <task> because that's what I use. If there were something better, I'd be using it, because I'm smart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not looking for just *languages*, but also for *frameworks*.  Any *language* that can access and call DLL functions can make Windows GUIs, since the Win32 API is just a series of DLLs.  But there are tons of GUI *frameworks* that sit on top of the Win32 API, and are written in tons of different *languages*.

Comment: I'm going to accept this before this question leads to a war lol.