# Adding buttons for POS

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, telerik

I was wondering what would be the best way to load buttons into a grid , im building a sample app for my own learning of a pos system and i need to be able to display category so was thinking a top row for the categories and the rest of the buttons would display the products what would my best way of implement this.

I have seen some pos systems also over a scrollwindow to achieve unlimited product selection any ideas would be appreciated

How would I load a button but keep them flowing correctly?

```
for(int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
   Button button[i] = new Button();
   // Button customization here...
   ...
   groupBox1.Controls.Add(button[i]);
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend WPF for any and all present and future Windows Desktop .Net UIs. winforms doesn't support anything, and the `unlimited scroll` feature you're after is much easier to implement in WPF with a simple [ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15532639/643085) in WPF due to built-in [UI Virtualization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA)

Comment: @HighCore I Suppose it is time to learn wpf but do you have any exmaples of wpf apps